# Nesting boost::multi_array?

Tags: c++, boost-multi-array

I have a template class which does some computation and returns multi_array, a bit oversimplified like this:

```
template <typename T>
class C
{
public:
    typedef boost::multi_array<T, 2> result_type;

    void do_something(T const& data, unsigned i, unsigned j); // add result to R[i][j]

    result_type R;
};
```

Instantiating the class with a simple type `T=double` works fine. Now, I want to instantiate with "`T=boost::multi_array<double, 1>`", but such that the result type is `boost::multi_array<double, 3>`.

The definition `multi_array<multi_array<T, N>, M>>` does clearly not result in `multi_array<T, N+M>`, it is just a N-dimensional multi_array with elements being M-dimensional multi_arrays ...

The idea to generate such a type is motivated by the Boost manual saying

> MultiArray is recursively defined; the containers at each level of
>   the container hierarchy model MultiArray as well.
>   Actually, it turns out that the "elements" of the intermediate `multi_array` levels are of type `subarray`.

Can one use `subarray` to generate a `multi_array` type with an effective dimensionality `N+M`? Maybe somehow along the following lines:

```
typedef typename boost::multi_array<double, 3>::subarray<1>::type value_type;
boost::multi_array<value_type, 2> a;
```

I'm looking for a relatively clean solution (not a lengthy hack), if this is not possible with the multi_array interface I will better rethink the design of what I'm going to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it makes no sense to instantiate `multi_array` with elements of type `multi_array` (although it might compile). For example, it would not lead to a contiguous memory layout since the elements manage memory themselves.

To solve the problem that motivated my question, I came up with the following solution:

```
template <typename T>
class C
{
    enum { extra_rank = get_rank<T>() };
public:
    typedef boost::multi_array<T, 2 + extra_rank> result_type;
}
```

The class defines a `multi_array` with extra dimensions depending on the type of `T`. The helper function `get_rank` checks whether `T` is `multi_array` and returns its `dimensionality`, otherwise it returns 0.

Comment: If you need to have a 2D array of 3D arrays with different sizes this will not work. A dynamic 2D array of dynamic 3D arrays is not equivalent to a dynamic 5D array. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it makes sense to instantiate a nested Boost.MA, `multi_array<multi_array<T, N>, M>>`.
However you are mistaken to think that this is equivalent to `multi_array<T, N + M>`, it is not.

Conceptually, this is because in the former case the nested arrays of dimensions `M` can have all different sizes.

In practice, even if all have the same sizes, the nested array will not be a contiguous (or regularly strided) memory.

Another *glitch* is that `multi_array`s do not have value semantic because the assignment fails (throws) for incompatible sizes, which is a bummer.
So, some reasonable manipulation of nested arrays could fail.

You can try my Multi array library for to workaround that glitch: https://godbolt.org/z/ec9K7Wzc4.